# Excel CSV import: Problem with line breaks from Superset export

Tags: excel, csv, apache-superset

When I export a CSV table from Apache Superset, some text columns include cells which may include line breaks (several lines of text in a cell).

Apple Pages has no problems importing the CSV file properly, but Excel gets all confused and messes up cells and rows. Is there a way convert them correctly when importing into Excel?

CSV excerpt with line break:

```
,"text text text (...) 

still more text",
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is encountered only when using the "File" -> "Import" feature.

I used "Data" ribbon -> "Power Query" instead. Importing the CSV works like charm and there is an option to ignore line breaks.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/text-csv

https://tsukaeru-excel.com/english-how-to-import-csv